# AngularJS: How would I go about selecting a single row from an array based on ID

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, angularjs, select

*THIS HAS BEEN UPDATED, AND IS FUNCTIONAL* Thank you @j.wittwer
http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/2xjuh/

I am trying to select a row from an array of posts based on ID. The goal behind selecting a single post is to create a single view where users can comment on a specific post.

I am unsure of what the best way to go about this is. I thought about just creating a model but I unsure how to select a single row in order to make that happen. I also would need to then select it with the form controller so that I can send that in the array back to ajax so that it gets posted in the array for that post.

I apologize if the code is messy firefox doesn't seem to like the formating Stack applies.

This is my JS code:(UPDATED)

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('FrmController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.visible = {
        post: 1
    };
    $scope.posts = [{
        id: 1,
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu laboramus persecuti cum, vel prompta ornatus democritum at, te alia partiendo pri. Ei quo sumo verear. Sed ad elitr aeterno disputationi, solum philosophia ex pro. Tempor essent prodesset in his, ne diam menandri vix, feugiat menandri ad cum.',
        comment: ['first!!', 'second!!']
    }, {
        id: 2,
        content: 'Facilisi pertinacia an nec. Veniam nostro commune ei pro, in mazim labores disputationi nec, cu habeo ludus deleniti ius. Id eripuit adolescens vis, mei nemore copiosae referrentur id. Pro ut ubique delicatissimi.',
        comment: ['great post!', 'tl;dr', 'interesting']
    }, {
        id: 3, 
        content: 'Sed fugit error cu. In cetero albucius insolens pri, an sea velit altera constituto. Et perpetua splendide sed, te vel solum doming contentiones. Pro no omnes ridens liberavisse, ea pri tale cetero laoreet, pro te essent civibus assueverit. Assum essent appareat mei te, duo aeque consulatu et, te mel reque facilisis.',
        comment: ['first to comment!']
    } ];
    $scope.btn_add = function (post, comment) {
        if (comment != '') {
            var IS_VALID = true;
        }

        if (IS_VALID) {
            console.log("The form was sent");
            post.comment.push(comment);
        }
    }

    $scope.remItem = function (post, $index) {
        post.comment.splice($index, 1);
    }
});
```

HTML:(UPDATED)

```
    <div ng-controller="FrmController">choose a post ({{visible.post}} is visible)
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts" style="display: inline; list-style-type: none;">
            <input type="button" ng-click="visible.post = post.id" value="{{post.id}}" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-if="visible.post == post.id">{{post.content}}
        <form>Post your Comment (for post {{post.id}})
            <textarea ng-model="txtcomment" placeholder="Your Comment" style='width:550px'></textarea>
            <button ng-click='btn_add(post, txtcomment);txtcomment = "";' style='margin-top:10px;'>Post Comment</button>
             <h4>Comments</h4>

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="comnt in post.comment">{{ comnt }}<a style="float: right;" href="" ng-click="remItem(post, $index)">x</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would filtering be a sufficient way to go about this? When the user clicks on one post, it then brings them to the second view where they see that post, only with the option to comment on that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to let `ng-click` set a variable indicating which post is visible/being commented on.  Then use that variable in `ng-if` to show the correct post.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <input type="button" ng-click="visible.post = post.id" value="{{post.id}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-if="visible.post == post.id">{{post.content}}
...
```

Here is a working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/2xjuh/

Comment: I need to be able to pull those variables from my Json data. I assume I would just stick that in the visible scope using $http or $resource. Except when I tried it, it either gave me an error or screwed with the rest of the page.

Comment: I suggest posting another question showing how you get the data, what the response data looks like, how you are trying to use it, and what the problem is.  Maybe make a fork of my fiddle, and replace the posts with the data you actually got.  Include a link to that fiddle in your question.